# possible to get inner text contents of dynamic angular class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So, I have a angular class setup like:

```
<h4 class="ng-binding">This changes & updates</h4>
```

I want to use a classic jQuery method to grab the current inner text contents? The below didn't work. Is this possible?

```
$('h4.ng-binding').text();
```

nor

```
$('.wrapper > h4.ng-binding').text();
```

*nor anything else in that fashion.*

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? Like $ is not a function or something?

Comment: where are you using jquery?  inside or outside of angularjs code?

Comment: outside in a seperate .js file (with just jQuery for organization purposes)

Comment: Maybe you are accessing the element before it is generated?

Comment: ng-binding is added by angular when the template is rendered. The class may not be there when your code runs. Use an explicit class name or an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give it an id:

```
$('#IdOfh4').text();
```

but if you want to use class to get the text rephrase your jquery command:

```
$('.ng-binding').text();
```

in case of having multiple instances of this class use each:

```
$('.ng-binding').each(function() {

console.log($(this).text());
});
```